# Верстка в bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Как сверстать блоки со стрелками по середине в bootstrap. Допустим взяли 3 блока и col-md-4, как же реализовать стрелки по середине ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы у 2 и3-го блоков сделал псевдо `:before` c `position: absolute; width: XX%; top: XXpx; display: block; border-top: 1px solid [color]`.